# apache - htaccess if/else with folder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, if-statement

I would like to exempt a directory from certain Apache rules. The directory is called "backup" (http://www.mydomain.de/backup) - but it also contains other directories and files. I imagine that but do not know the right approach:

```
if( "backup folder" in url){
    //my rules rules for the folder
}
else{ 
    //my other rules
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a separate .htaccess in your backup folder that overrides the base .htaccess. I think that's the best practice and will save you (or someone else) a lot of time if you have to debug it later.

Comment: it is a virtual directory that does not exist ... Everything is controlled by an index.php, so I need an if query!